# Is anyone aware of a mirror for CloudLoop, the open source project that was located here: http://svn.cloudloop.com/svn/cloudloop/

Tags: svn, cloud

I'm looking to check out the code for the opensource project CloudLoop, but the svn repo is offline and no one seems to respond to inquiries.  Can someone provide a mirror for what was stored at: http://svn.cloudloop.com/svn/cloudloop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe here: https://cloudloop.dev.java.net/source/browse/cloudloop/